# Twenty Eleven NOT valid

Tags: themes, theme-twenty-eleven

How come the default theme Twenty Eleven fails validation test, both for HTML5 and CSS3? I checked: http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/

Should I be bothered that the validation fails?

Comment: HTML/CSS validation is a *tool*, not a strict rule.

Comment: Unfortunately some people see it as a rule...

Answer (score 1):

Validation is a tricky topic. It is good to have, but it is also theoretical thing in practical world.

I had [checked that URL with Unicorn](http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/check?ucn_uri=twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/&ucn_task=conformance#).

- It explicitly says that HTML5 checking is not considered reliable and errors are mostly attribute related (which is verrry unlikely to be an issues).
- CSS errors seem to be related to multiple browser-specific feature. Annoying? Yes. Possible to get by without? Will need to sacrifice some eye-candy.

My opinion is that unless you are dead set to only using perfectly validating themes on principle, then Twenty Eleven is not for you or you will need to create child theme and clean it up.

If you are concerned that Twenty Eleven just might have horrible markup/CSS issues - that is unlikely in theme of such high profile.

Comment: And if one wants to use only perfectly validating code, then one must avoid HTML5-based Themes until the spec is finalized and the validator settles on the finalized spec. Likewise with CSS3, for which browser-specific attribute prefixes are perfectly acceptable per the draft spec, but which the validator doesn't recognize.